# How to delete previously printed string before printing the new string

Tags: c, conio

I am using [outtextxy](http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c/graphics.h/outtextxy) from `conio` to print a string at a particular point in C.Whenever `outtextxy` is executed for some coordinates it works perfectly.The problem occurs whenever `outtextxy` is executed for same set of coordinates again but with another string.The newly printed string is overwritten on the previously written screen.I would like to know how to delete previously printed string before printing the new string(I can't clear the whole screen but only the string printed at particular coordinates) ?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that a space character is indistinguishable from the background, you can erase a string by writing a space character over each coordinate the string covers.

Alternatively, you can write your string out and pad the trailing difference with spaces.

This requires you to keep track of what you have written where, so you know how much you need to overwrite.